# How to hide browser window status bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a popup window with full screen video without having the browser's status bar visible.

I am trying to keep messages like `Transferring data from www.google.com` and  `Waiting for www.google.com` out of view as they distract from the video.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What all have you tried so far?

Comment: @mattytommo -- its already in iframe but, loading from youtube.com message displayed below the screen.

Comment: use the [Full-Screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode)?

Comment: Maybe browser vendors think it is unsafe to not show where a link goes or from where it stream?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen the following `javascript` snippet around some sites, but it seems deprecated long ago.

```
window.status = "";
```

This is what w3schools tells me (source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp)):

> **Note:** The status property does not work in the default configuration of IE, Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. To allow scripts to
>   change the text of the status, the user must set the
>   dom.disable_window_status_change preference to false in the
>   about:config screen. (or in Firefox: "Tools - Options - Content
>   -Enable JavaScript / Advanced - Allow scripts to change status bar text").

So it is a user configuration. Honestly, I don't like the idea of webpages messing around with my browser, it could cause some serious security issues.

Why don't you use a javascript popup window, like [Modalbox](http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html) or using [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/)?

Comment: Maybe status is turned off because of security reason so info can not be turned of about where a hovered link goes or from where it stream?